# QC_Hit : no for all the queries logged in my slow query log

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb, query-optimization, query-cache

Following is a sample line from my slow query log:

```
>Thread_id: 478  Schema: schema_one  QC_hit: No
>
>Query_time: 3.725316  Lock_time: 0.000030  Rows_sent: 10  Rows_examined: 442611
>
>Rows_affected: 0  Bytes_sent: 2703
```

For all the queries running in the server, the QC_hit is No only!. But I have set almost 16M for the query cache.

Updated: I am using 10.4.17-MariaDB.

Do the settings or my code affecting the cache?

Comment: "The query cache is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20, and is removed in MySQL 8.0" says the MySQL documentation. Please [edit] your question to tell us which version you use.

Comment: I have updated the Question. Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Have you read MariaDB's documentation on configuring the query cache? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-cache/ It's disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to enable the query cache by adding `query_cache_type=1` to your configuration:

> To see if the cache is enabled, view the query_cache_type server variable. It is enabled by default in MariaDB versions up to 10.1.6, but disabled starting with MariaDB 10.1.7 - if needed enable it by setting query_cache_type to 1.

Comment: I enabled the cache in the Maria db Server with query_cache_type and query_cache_size fields/variables. But the queries are not cached in the server with Query cache so QC_hit is set to No. How can I know whether the queries are cached? based on memory size?

Comment: There are [some limitations to the query cache](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query-cache/#queries-stored-in-the-query-cache) that prevent certain statements from being cached. Certain obvious ones like `NOW()` cause the cache to be skipped completely.

Comment: `query_cache_limit` needs to be more than about 2703, according to "Bytes sent".  What is your value?